# How do I select records where its related records do not have a specific attribute-value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I want to select all of the users who do not have associated posts where the title is, 'test123'. The following syntax is not working:

```
User.includes(:posts).where.not(posts: { title: 'test123' })
```

How do I select users whose associated posts do not have a specific title?

**UPDATE**

Originally, I tried to isolate where exactly I thought I was having the problem, but I want to show the query that most closely reflects what I am doing. The problem is still with the, where.not, clause. It's returning an empty array when I know there are records with posts that have other titles.

```
User.where("users.created_at >= ? and users.created_at <= ?", 1.month.ago.utc, 1.week.ago.utc)
    .where(active: true)
    .includes(:comments)
    .where('comments.id is not null')
    .includes(:posts)
    .where.not(posts: { title: 'test123'} )
    .references(:posts)
```

Comment: Try `User.includes(:posts).where.not(posts: { title: 'test123' }).references(:posts)`

Comment: The spirit of the question has not changed, but I thought I add some more complexity to the problem to provide more context. I tried your solution, by the way, and I am still getting an empty array. I also have the model associations wired up correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem was with executing inner vs outer joins with Active Record Query Syntax. The problem with this query:

`User.includes(:posts).where.not(posts: { title: 'test123' })`

is that it evaluates, where.not(posts: { title: 'test123'}), only after retrieving all the user records with an associated post -- leaving behind all of the other user records who do not have a corresponding post. I wanted a query that would not exclude the Users without posts.

This is how I did it:

```
User.where("users.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) from posts where title = 'test123')")
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [***API Doc***](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes)

> If you want to add conditions to your included models you’ll have to
>   explicitly reference them

So the below query will work

```
User.includes(:posts).where.not(posts: { title: 'test123' }).references(:posts)
```

Comment: This still gives me an empty array but if you check the question again, I have updated it to increase its complexity which more accurately reflects the problem I am trying to solve.